# How to drop a table using mouse and context menu or main menu on DBeaver?

Tags: database, user-interface, developer-tools, ux, dbeaver

DBeaver is rather good with all the necessary features.

However, something is missing. I'm using DBeaver to connect to PostgreSQL. The UI shows databases, table list, etc., right-clicking on a table would open context menu. The context menu allows creating generic SQL commands.

The missing one is the 'drop table' menu item, especially, when I need to **drop multiple tables**.

There's no such 'drop table' menu item on context menu or main menu? I would like to select multiple tables to drop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delete functionality is hidden by default, but it is there when using the `Advanced` connection view.

You can enter the view by right clicking on the connection you're using and changing `Connection view` from Simple to Advanced. After it prompts you to restart the connection, a `Delete` option will appear in the context menu when selecting tables. This will allow you to instantly delete one or multiple tables in two clicks.